# SSRS Report Passivity between database versions

Tags: mysql, reporting-services

I need to maintain report passivity between versions of a database.
The database is released to customers with upgrades adding new columns to existing tables.  How can i maintain a single report that will run on all released databases.
I tried if exists(select new column from table)
begin
select with new column
end 
else
select without new column
end

I error on the older database. with Invalid Column Name

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a view for this. The view is updated as the tables are updated to include the new columns. Any application then just selects * from view and itterates the resultset. No need to modify application code. If you are modifying the database then you include updating the view in the process.